# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on $register

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

This is basically my first time using PHP. I'm trying to create a reservation system, but I've been stuck at the registration page for a good while now. I end up getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\feha\registration.php on line 57". Line 57 is:

```
    $register = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users' (username, password, fname, lname, address, contact) VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."','".$fname."','".$lname."','".$address."','".$contact."')");
```

I've tried using a backslash before the "INSERT... and the error no longer appears, but nothing else does, for that matter. It's supposed to display a message if the user has been registered or if there was an error. I've also tried just using single quotes on the values, taking out the quotes on the table name, removing the column names.

It fixes it temporarily, but then another parse error appears further into my program, I fix it somehow, until it shows an error about unexpected $end at line 62 (my closing line). This is my entire code:

```
    <?php
    include 'connectdb.php';//database connection
    if (isset($_POST['register']))
    {
    //input fields
    $register = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['register']));
    $username = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['username']));
    $fname = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['fname']));
    $lname = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['lname']));
    $address = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['address']));
    $contact = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['contact']));
    $email = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $repeat = strip_tags($_POST['repeat']);
    //check for values
    $errors = array();
    if ($username&&$fname&&$lname &&$address&& $contact&& $email&&
    $password&&$repeat)
    {
    if ($password!=$repeat) ///check if pw match


    {
    die("Your password does not match!");


    }//check char length of username
    if (strlen($username)<6||strlen($username)>32)

    {
    die ("Username must be between 6 and 32 characters");
    }

    //checking for password length
    if (strlen(strlen($password)<8||$password)>12)
    {
    die ("Password must be between 8 - 12 characters");
    }

    //encrypt password
    $password = md5($password);
    //check if username already taken
    $check = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($check)>=1)
    {
    die ("Username already taken);
    }
    if (!empty($errors))
    {
    foreach ($errors as $error)
    {
    echo $error, '<br/>';
    }
    }
    else
    {
    $register = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users' (username, password, fname, lname, address, contact) VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."','".$fname."','".$lname."','".$address."','".$contact."')");
    echo '<div id="good">You have been registered succesfully! ';}
    }
    else{echo "Please fill in all the fields";}
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: close the die() string with double quotes.

Comment: @shapeshifter I think he's missing a quote not semi colon

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a tutorial site to explain the syntax basics of a programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be,

```
die ("Username already taken");
```